# Plotly plot-container is not removed on Shiny Input Error

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly

In the case of an input error Plotly does not remove the plot-container (see screenshot), and the Shiny error div is a sibling of the parent div (i.e. trendPlot in this example) rather than replacing the plot-container as is done with other Shiny plotting libraries like highcharts using rCharts.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to make plot-container disappear on a Shiny input error?

- Online App: https://plotly.shinyapps.io/UN-Simple/
- App code: https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-UN-simple/

[image: Plot bug on Shiny input error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/893) resolved by the plotly package developers.